# JS: Why FOR LOOP loops once?

Tags: javascript, loops, object, for-loop

Why I get only one alert after run this code:

```
var poly = function()
{
   this.disp = function()
   {
      for(var i=0; i<6; i++);        //And I already found my problem. It is this ';'
      {
           alert('The number is '+i);        //I get one alert: 'The number is 6'
      } 
   }
}

test = new poly();
test.disp();
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Works for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/FvVb2/

Comment: Where in your code you use this code? I just copied and pasted it to console and I got 6 different alerts. Ii really matters how do you use this in your actual code.

Comment: I'm confused. Yes in fiddle works. In poly object is more functions and methods, not just 'this.disp'. But I don't think that another loops in others methods can make problem in disp function. Because when I check 'i' before loop, the I get error that 'i is undefined'. So the 'i' is 0 at the loop start.

Comment: don't use `alert()` use rather `console.log()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works. Probably, in your *real* code, it looks like this:

```
var poly = function()
{
   this.disp = function()
   {
      for(var i=0; i<6; i++)
      {
      } 
      alert('The number is '+i);        //I get one alert: 'The number is 6'
   }
}
```

That will cause i to loop from 0 to 6, after which it is alerted once.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This is my eyes problem :D My code was: 

for(var i=0; i<6; i++);
{
   //stuff
}

Comment: :) For the next time, make sure that the snippet you post contains the actual error, otherwise we will be looking for a non-existent needle in a haystack. ;)

Comment: @EdvinasPranka try this demo (now it uses console.log) http://jsbin.com/bebem/1/edit?js,console but if you change to alert() it'll show you just `The number is 0`